# What is the purpose of data as a parameter in fs.readFile?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why is data required as a parameter in fs.readFile function?

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./SampleFile.txt', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    const content = data;

        console.log(content);  
    
});
```

Comment: Without the `data` parameter you won't have access to the contents of the file. You can give it any name, e.g. `myData`.

Answer (score 2):

callback_function: It is a callback function that is called after reading of the file. It takes two parameters:

err: If any error occurred.

data: Contents of the file.

Comment: I am sorry if I framed the question incorrectly, I understand that data contains the contents of the file. What I meant to ask was why does the readFile callback function is parameterized with data as parameter? For e.g in readFileSync we can simply store the contents of the file in a variable, like : var contents = fs.readFileSync('sample.txt','utf-8');
contents now contain the data, but in the async readFile we need data as a parameter. Hope you understand what I meant now.

Comment: Thats because how async operations work, by convention first arg of callback is error or null, second is actual data that async function returns in this case its content.

if you are using readFileSync you can store content in variable indeed, but then you also need to try/catch the error:

`try { const data = fs.readFileSync(path) } catch (error) { console.log(error) }`

IDK if it answers you question, tell me :)