# Why is data a parameter in the async readFile function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I understand that data contains the contents of the file.

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./SampleFile.txt', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    const content = data;

        console.log(content);  
    
});
```

What I mean to ask is why is the readFile callback function  parameterized with data as parameter?

For e.g in readFileSync we can simply store the contents of the file in a variable, like :

```
var contents = fs.readFileSync('sample.txt','utf-8');
```

contents now contain the data of the file.
But in the async readFile function we have data as a parameter and we can't do something like:

```
var contents = fs.readFile('sample.txt','utf-8',(err)=>{
     if(err){
        //Handle Error
     }
}
```

Why is that?

Comment: Because it's async and async functions work via callbacks. That's how JS works ...

Comment: You have already asked this question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69028385/what-is-the-purpose-of-data-as-a-parameter-in-fs-readfile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because async functions are working asynchronous and it's is part of the JS concurrency model which is based on an event loop which is responsible for executing the code, collecting and processing events.

The result from reading the file in an asynchronous will be received later from the environment where JS is running (which is Node.js in your case or the browser if the JS code is running in client side) and will be placed in the callback queue to be fetched later when the event loop will pick up his next item to be placed in the callstack to be executed (this is just a simple introduction to the JS event loop)

If you are using Node v11.0.0, you can use the fs promises which are available natively and allow you to use async/await and are readabl, clearer then the callback functions.

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;

async function readFile() {
  const data = await fs.readFile("./SampleFile.txt");
  return new Buffer(data);
}
```

More about the callbacks and the JS event loop - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop